# I am getting an "error" that says "requestCursorUpdates" are not supported... In Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I created a custom outline search box for my app. The search box is supposed to filter out the list as you type inside of it. But I am getting this "error" without it being flagged as an error.

```
W/RecordingIC: requestCursorUpdates is not supported
W/RecordingIC: requestCursorUpdates is not supported
W/RecordingIC: requestCursorUpdates is not supported
W/RecordingIC: requestCursorUpdates is not supported
W/RecordingIC: requestCursorUpdates is not supported
W/RecordingIC: requestCursorUpdates is not supported
W/RecordingIC: requestCursorUpdates is not supported
W/RecordingIC: requestCursorUpdates is not supported
W/RecordingIC: requestCursorUpdates is not supported
W/RecordingIC: requestCursorUpdates is not supported
W/RecordingIC: requestCursorUpdates is not supported
W/RecordingIC: requestCursorUpdates is not supported
W/RecordingIC: requestCursorUpdates is not supported
W/RecordingIC: requestCursorUpdates is not supported
W/RecordingIC: requestCursorUpdates is not supported
W/RecordingIC: requestCursorUpdates is not supported
W/RecordingIC: requestCursorUpdates is not supported
W/RecordingIC: requestCursorUpdates is not supported
W/RecordingIC: requestCursorUpdates is not supported
W/RecordingIC: requestCursorUpdates is not supported
```

it occurs every time I type in the search bar. I do believe that the search bar isn't picking up what I am typing in it, thus the error.

Here's the code -
The ViewModel:

```
  private var _anyInfoResults = MutableStateFlow<List<AnywhereListEntity>>(emptyList())
    val anyInfoResults = _anyInfoResults.asStateFlow()



    private var cachedSearch = listOf<AnywhereListEntity>()
    private var isSearchStarting = true
    var isSearching = mutableStateOf(false)


  fun searchAnywhereList(query: String){
        val listToSearch = if(isSearchStarting){ _anyInfoResults.value }
                            else { cachedSearch }
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default){
            if (query.isEmpty()){
                _anyInfoResults.value = cachedSearch
                isSearching.value = false
                isSearchStarting = true
                return@launch
            }
            val results = listToSearch.filter {
                it.name.contains(query, ignoreCase = true)
            }
            if (isSearchStarting){
                cachedSearch = _anyInfoResults.value
                isSearchStarting = false
            }
            _anyInfoResults.value = results
            isSearching.value = true
        }
    }
```

The Search Bar

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun SearchBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onSearch: (String) -> Unit = {}
) {
    val searchQueryState = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    val valid = remember(searchQueryState.value){
        searchQueryState.value.trim().isNotEmpty()
    }
    Column {
        Surface(modifier.padding(bottom = 10.dp),
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.primaryVariant) {
            CommonTextField(
                valueState = searchQueryState,
                placeholder = "Search",
                onAction = KeyboardActions {
                    if (!valid) return@KeyboardActions
                    onSearch(searchQueryState.value.trim())
                    searchQueryState.value = ""
                    keyboardController?.hide()
                }
            )
        }
    }

}

@Composable
fun CommonTextField(
    valueState: MutableState<String>,
    placeholder: String,
    keyboardType: KeyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
    imeAction: ImeAction = ImeAction.Next,
    onAction: KeyboardActions = KeyboardActions.Default
) {
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = valueState.value,
        onValueChange = { valueState.value = it },
        label = { Text(text = placeholder, color = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary) },
        maxLines = 1,
        singleLine = true,
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = keyboardType, imeAction = imeAction),
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
            focusedBorderColor = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
            cursorColor = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
            textColor = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
            unfocusedBorderColor = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary
        ),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(start = 10.dp, end = 10.dp)
    )

}
```

I'll leave my project on GitHub open for further clarification. Thank You.

Github link: https://github.com/OEThe11/AnywhereCE